# Some non-ascii characters display as dots in an application in wine

Tags: wine

It looks like this: [image: dots displayed]. 
What is wrong with this?

Comment: what is the language you are using, and what are the contents of the `locale` command please?

Comment: The system is en-US and the application is in Chinese.